# Resources for engineering with wood

Tags: materials, wood

I'm an engineering student and I've just taken my first solid mechanics course and I absolutely loved it! However, most of the problems in the textbook tend to deal with materials like steel, copper, and aluminum. I'd love to learn more about how to apply my knowledge to things which are built out of wood, where the material properties differ based on the grain's orientation.

I have tried looking up material properties of wood before and I've had a hard time finding straight forward answers. I was wondering if anyone would be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Generally thev will be older references. I have on on building wood pipe , I think it is about 100 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2018 National Design Specification (NDS) for Wood Construction is a comprehensive guide with worked-out examples.

This is the 2018 version. if you google NDS or AWC there are many free educational books on wood construction codes and guides available.

[NDS 2018](https://The%202018%20National%20Design%20Specification%20(NDS)%20for%20Wood%20Construction)